# Rerender is not triggered within <apex:repeat> block

Tags: rerender, actionsupport, repeat, outputpanel

I have a scenario where there are repeating Tabs. Within each tab, there are multiple drop-down lists (say DL1, DL2, DL3). DL2 is dynamically generated based on the value selected from DL1. And DL3 is dynamically generated based on the value from DL2. I implemented something similar as:

```
<apex:repeat id="repeat1" value="{!reps}" var="rep">
.
.
.
    <div id="div1-{!rep.id}">
        <apex:outputPanel id="DL1" >
            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedVal1}" size="1" id="SL1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!list1}" />                                                                                                                                
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="DL2"/>                                         
            </apex:selectList>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </div> 
    <div id="div2-{!rep.id}">
        <apex:outputPanel id="DL2" >
            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedVal2}" size="1" id="SL2">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!list2}" />                                                                                                                                
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="DL3"/>                                         
            </apex:selectList>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </div>          
    <div id="div3-{!rep.id}">
        <apex:outputPanel id="DL3" >
            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedVal3}" size="1" id="SL3">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!list3}" />                                                          
            </apex:selectList>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </div>
.
.
.
</apex:repeat>
```

Issue: Rerender is not getting triggered on DL1. This seems to be because this is within the "repeat" because I have a similar feature implemented outside repeat and it works without any issues.

I tried the following options after browsing several links but still no luck

1. Set Outputpanel layout attribute to "none"
2. Tried to assign a dymanic id to Outputpanel. But VisualForce throws error " Literal value is required for attribute id in <apex:outputPanel>"
3. Modified code to rerender as rerender="repeat1:DL2"
4. Modified code to rerender as rerender = "{!$Component.DL2}

I am a newbie to SalesForce. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't your div ids merge in `{!rep}` and not `{!var}`?

Comment: Also just a hunch...you may want to look into picklist dependencies so you can configure this behavior instead.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - You are correct, the div ids are merged with {!rep.id}. I typed them by mistake, I corrected it now.   The data for the drop down lists are pulled via external webservices. Hence the drop down lists has to be dynamic... I am also looking for other options to make it work.. If nothing helps, moving outside the repeat would work but I want that to be the last option.. thanks for your comment..

Comment: Well the other issue is you have id collision, every iteration through your `repeat` generates another `outputPanel` whose id is "DL1". Unfortunately I don't think you can merge values into standard component ids. Have you tried rerendering the entire `repeat`?

Comment: Tried now to set `rerender` to `repeat` id, this is not triggering too.

Comment: Are you sure the value is getting updated? Maybe include some relevant controller code. Doesn't look like the picklist options vary by rep.

Comment: If I am getting your question right, I printed the value of `selectedVal1` (value selected in `DL1` ) in the controller code and it is correct. So looks like the value is set.  These pick lists are not dependent on rep but there are couple of more, that are dependent and all these need to be grouped together within the rep.

Comment: Just a wild guess, your outputPanel resides under a div tag, so you can try rerendering the next whole div tag. May work!

Comment: @SantanuHalder - No, it doesn't work even outside the repeat, I have tried that before. Initially I didn't have `OutputPanel` within the `div`, that is the reason I added `OutputPanel` for rerender to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help! The issue is fixed now after the below changes

1. Unknowingly I had the `selectList` value declared as both the list and the getter by mistake which prevented the onchange event to trigger. I removed those duplicates.
2. As the `selectList` value was static, the value was not set correctly. Modified it to store in a Map so that it can be dynamic for each repeat